# Proper use of とか and そして in a sentence

Tags: grammar

I have a "Fairly" simple paragraph that I have written.

Hello, Im Kyle.
こんにちは、カイルと申します。

Im 29 years old **and** (そして) my favourite music is Rock **and** (とか) Classical.
二十九歳だそして好きな音楽はロックミュージックとかクラッシックだ。

As for your favourite music, what is it?
あなたの好きな音楽は何だか.

Im curious about two things here:

1. The use of そして for connecting the first sentence with the second, I had heard that そして can sometimes be used for comparing sentences?
2. The use of とか for a simple list (of things like or for example).

For such a short list, is there a better way to write this sentence rather than using とか?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Im Kyle. こんにちは、カイルと申します。
```

That's fine.

```
Im 29 years old and my favourite music is Rock and Classical
```

（私は）２９歳**で**、好きな音楽はロック**と**クラシック**です**。

とか means "or" while と means "and".
When you combine ２９歳 だ/です and …クラシック だ/です, they are merged into ２９歳で…クラシック だ/です. And let's follow the first 申し**ます** in the point of politeness.

```
As for your favourite music, what is it?
```

あなたの好きな音楽は何（ですか）？

You don't say 何だか for that.

Comment: Thank you! I understand now that だ can't be used with a question. です should be used instead. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes.  You should use either 何？ or  何ですか?.